# CSS Twitter Bootstrap Form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble implementing a form in Twitter Bootstrap2.

I've set up a JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/manishap/WNSCW/15/

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="ratingSubectives" class="row-fluid">
    <form class="well" >
        <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <label class="control-label" for="select01">Aaaaaaaaaaaa</label>
                <div class="controls"><select id="select01">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                </select></div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <label class="control-label" for="select02">Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</label>
                <div class="controls"><select id="select02">
                    <option></option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="A">B</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                </select></div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <label class="control-label" for="select03"><a href="#">Ccccccccccc</a></label>
                <div class="controls"><select id="select03" disabled>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="C">C</option>
                </select></div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <label class="control-label" for="select03">&nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls"><button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>             
 </div>
```

I'm trying to place 3 select controls with labels horizontally across a div. It looks right in English with short labels. However, eventually this is a site that is delivered in multiple languages, and if the labels get long (as in the middle selector), the label text overlaps the text next to it. How do I get the text to wrap?

I tried adding a max-width: 100%, as per another answer and that didn't work. Maybe I put the labels in divs instead of label tags...

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) attribute to break the word:

```
.control-label {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```